# Number of degrees of freedom of parallel mechanism

Tags: robotics, linkage

[image]

Can anyone provide me with the number of degrees of freedom (translational and/or rotational) at point P?

Edit with my assumptions:
[image]

The left picture shows the mechanism from the side and the right picture shows the mechanism from above. My assumption is that at point P there is 3 translational degrees of freedom and one rotational degree of freedom. I would like to have some sort of proof that my assumptions are correct.

Comment: Why don't you explain your solution then we might help.

Comment: @SolarMike fair enough, I added my assumption to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  4 DOF.  The 4 bar linkage has 1 and the three parallel joints each have one.  For robotic manipulators you just add them up.